# TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable after resetting index on Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Getting this error when trying to reset index for a simple pandas dataframe.

My input is:

`df2 = a.reset_index(drop=True)`

Output

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-97-68f172e9a129> in <module>()
----> 1 df2 = a.reset_index(drop=True)
      2 df2`

TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

This doesn't usually happen when I reset indices and also couldn't find anything on here when the error involves a reset.

Thanks

Comment: What is `a`? Have you tried `df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)` ?

Comment: or a.reset_index(drop=True, inplace = True) ?

Comment: a is the name of the dataframe. df2 is the new name I'm assigning it so that isn't working @jpp

Comment: @snow_fall, you need to provide more code. Read through *[mcve]* for what's expected, so we can reproduce your problem in its entirety.

Comment: @jpp thank you, I understand that but this is quite an isolated issue - i think It may have assigned something to the dataframe 'a' before hand. no problem I've fixed it

Answer (score 0):

So this was an isolated situation - I've been able to solve this problem by assigning the dataframe a new name. There may have been an override at one point while I was coding, which I wasn't aware of.

Instead of 'a' 
`a.reset_index(drop=True)` went back and changed the

`a = pd.read_csv('../xyz')` to `x = pd.read_csv...` 
or wherever in your code you can change the name and continued with 
`df = x.reset_index(drop=True)` which works!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Before the error, I entered a code below.

```
df.reset_index = True
```

Even though this code doesn't make any sense, it doesn't makes any error.

It just assigned '**True**' Boolean value to `df.reset_index`

Thus, there was no effect on `df`.
-> Computer thinks `df.reset_index(drop = True)` I am trying to call function which is actually Boolean.

I guess you made the similar mistake.

[image]